# What four TV series appeared on Sci-Fi channel about the same time around March 1999?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I recall seeing four new TV series that appeared on the SciFi channel about the same time.  Two of them were *Farscape* and *First Wave*.  Unfortunately, I cannot recall the other two.  According to IMDb, they both started in the US on the SciFi channel in early 1999.  Can anyone tell me the other two?

Comment: "*The big day is tomorrow, when the Sci-Fi Channel launches two new series [Farscape and First Wave[ along with new episodes of "Sliders" -- that show is harder to kill than Rasputin -- and "Poltergeist: The Legacy."*" - - https://www.sfgate.com/entertainment/article/Invasion-Sci-Fi-Channel-expands-its-universe-2941269.php

Comment: Why the votedown?

Comment: @Moriarty - Possibly for a lack of research?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Syfy), *Farscape* debuted on the Sci-Fi (SyFy) Channel on March 19, 1999 and *First Wave* debuted on September 9, 1998.

Other shows that debuted in that general time frame were:

- *Sliders*, which was not a new show.  It debuted on Sci-Fi on Jun 6, 1998, but previously had been on FOX.
- *Poltergeist: The Legacy* debuted on the Sci-Fi Channel on March 19, 1999, but it previously had been on Showtime.
- *Welcome to Paradox* debuted on August 17, 1998. This was an anthology series where all the stories took place in Betaville.
- *Good vs. Evil* debuted on July 18, 1999.  A comedy sci-fi series about God recruiting people who had died to help fight demons.  It is currently showing on NBC's Chiller channel.

Other shows debuted before 1998 or after 1999.